# How to print the current time in a Batch-File?

Tags: batch-file, time

I need to print time in a batch file but command prompt tells me that the syntax is incorrect.
Here is the code i have so far:

```
@echo %time%
ping -n 1 -w 1 127.0.0.1 1>nul
@echo %time%
pause
cls
```

I don't know why it isn't working, Please help Me.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Copying your exact code, pasting into a new empty batch file, saving it, and running it produces no errors and displays the output I'd expect.

Comment: works for me too in windows 10

Comment: What windows version are you using?

Comment: *`that the syntax is incorrect`* -- please exact paste the message you get!

Comment: The %DATE% and %TIME% are read *once*. These values remain constant throughout the execution of the batch file, irrespective of any actual change in date or time.

Comment: Why would you think that, FractalSpace? A simple "sleep "test shows %DATE% & %TIME% are updated during execution of the batch file.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you use the command

```
time /T
```

that will print the time. (without the /T, it will try to set the time)

```
date /T
```

is similar for the date.

If cmd's Command Extensions are enabled (they are enabled by default, but in this question they appear to be disabled), then the environment variables `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` will expand to the current date and time each time they are expanded. The format used is the same as the `DATE` and `TIME` commands.

To see the other dynamic environment variables that exist when Command Extensions are enabled, run `set /?`.

Answer (score 148):

This works with Windows 10, 8.x, 7, and possibly further back:

```
@echo Started: %date% %time%
.
.
.
@echo Completed: %date% %time%
```

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7.

Comment: on Windows 8.1 as well

Comment: Works in Windows 10 as well.

Comment: and still working on windows 11

Answer (score 18):

we can easily print the current time and date using `echo` and `system` variables as below.

```sh
echo %DATE% %TIME%
```

output example: 13-Sep-19 15:53:05.62

Comment: Here are already 3 answers, showing the date and time variables. I can't see how your answer adds any more informations to that

Comment: it doesn't work, it reads time once it then these vars are useless

Answer (score 3):

```
echo %TIME% & echo. & echo %DATE%
```

The output will be:

*14:35:47,88*

*Pzt 24.10.2022*

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way using just DOS is `echo. | time`.

This method even works in a Windows 7 x64 Command window.

Comment: FYI, Stackoverflow supports markdown syntax. Enclose code/commands with \` to show up as a `code block`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your question was answered.

This will write the time & date every 20 seconds in the file ping_ip.txt. The second to last line just says run the same batch file again, and agan, and again,..........etc.

Does not seem to create multiple instances, so that's a good thing.

```
@echo %time% %date% >>ping_ip.txt
ping -n 20 -w 3 127.0.0.1 >>ping_ip.txt
This_Batch_FileName.bat
cls
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the command `time /t` for the time and `date /t` for the date, here is an example:

```
@echo off
time /t >%tmp%\time.tmp
date /t >%tmp%\date.tmp
set ttime=<%tmp%\time.tmp
set tdate=<%tmp%\date.tmp
del /f /q %tmp%\time.tmp
del /f /q %tmp%\date.tmp
echo Time: %ttime%
echo Date: %tdate%
pause >nul
```

You can also use the built in variables %time% and %date%, here is another example:

```
@echo off
echo Time: %time:~0,5%
echo Date: %date%
pause >nul
```

Comment: `set ttime=<%tmp%\time.tmp` surely doesn't work as intended.